# Error executing a Query using JPA

Tags: java, mysql, jpa

I'm trying to sort a resultset using the SQL statement Order by using JPA, on a datetime column data type with this string, on a Mysql database:

```
Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT e FROM Events e Order by e.EventDateTime;");
```

Using the createQuery method java returns the error:

```
SEVERE: Local Exception Stack: 
Exception [EclipseLink-8030] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.0.v20110604-r9504): 

org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.JPQLException
Exception Description: Error compiling the query [Events.findByGameId: SELECT e FROM Events e WHERE e.gameId = 

:gameId ORDER BY e.EventDateTime DESC], line 1, column 59: unknown state or association field [EventDateTime] of class [com.jogogestao.entity.Events].
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.JPQLException.unknownAttribute(JPQLException.java:457)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.parsing.DotNode.validate(DotNode.java:88)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.parsing.OrderByItemNode.validate(OrderByItemNode.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.parsing.OrderByNode.validate(OrderByNode.java:61)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.parsing.ParseTree.validate(ParseTree.java:210)
```

I tried sorting by the integer type primary and all runs ok...but this is not what I want of course.
Using createNativeQuery the statement runs ok...

```
Query query = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT * FROM Events Order by EventDateTime;");
```

The only problem is that the return object is not an Events type object (from the entity) and I can't convert to this type.

Maybe the problem is that JPA does not support sorting on datetime fields?

How can I get around this?

I'm using Netbeans 7.0.1, Glassfish 3.1.1, MySql 5.5.19  Community Server (GPL) and mysql-connector-java-5.1.15-bin.jar.

Thanks!

Comment: Is `EventDateTime` the name of the field in `com.jogogestao.entity.Events` or the name of the table column?

Comment: Is the ";" at the end of the query the issue? Just a guess since it gives parsing error

Comment: It's the name of the column weltraumpirat

Comment: @Dhanush Gopinath - I tried all...with ; , without ;, ORDER BY e.EventDateTime ASC and DESC...but no luck:(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT e FROM Event e ORDER BY e.eventDateTime
```

- you don't have `*` - you have to specify the entity you select
- don't put a semicolon at the end
- use all-lower-case keywords, capital-case entity names, and lower-camel-case property names
- name the entity in singular, not plural (`Event` vs `Events`)

Comment: Thank you it's solved! The problem was that I didn't know the statements were case sensitive...e.EventDateTime does not work but e.eventDateTime works. Does the case need to be the same as the one used by the entity?

Comment: yes. you are querying for objects, so refer to their properties

Answer (score 0):

The message is clear: you don't have an `EventDateTime` mapped property (or field, if fields are mapped directly) in the entity Events. If you respect the Java conventions, the field/property should be named `eventDateTime`, and not `EventDateTime`.